# Add an array of string to an array list of the array's of strings

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, nested

So in my program I split the first row of data imported by a csv file into an array. Is there anyway that I can add this array into an array list as the first element? Because once I split the second data into an array by a delimiter I then want to store this array in the same arraylist but in element 2. A bit confusing but to summarize is nested arrays in an arraylist possible?

```java
public static ArrayList<String[]> readCSV(Scanner csv, String delimiter, int minCellsPerRow) {
  String line = csv.nextLine();
  String[] parts = line.split(delimiter);
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  list.add(parts);
}
```

Comment: `list.add(list.size(), parts)`

Comment: tag this post as Java, and syntax highlighting turns on :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify insertion index with list.add()... here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //setup
    ArrayList<String> storage;

    storage = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("4","5","6"));

    String[] data = {"1","2","3"};

    printMe(storage);

    //append
    storage.addAll(0, Arrays.asList(data));

    printMe(storage);
}

public static void printMe(ArrayList<String> strs) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strs.toArray(new String[0])));
}
```

yields the console result:

```
[4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

would this work in your case?